# Creating Virtual Machines using ubuntu-vm-builder

Tags: apt, kernel, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm currently trying to install virtual machines on my Ubuntu Server 13.10. I followed the instructions from this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests). I was able to install and check that my machine is supported, but when I run the command:

```
sudo ubuntu-vm-builder kvm saucy
```

(I would have to add other options)

it takes several minutes. The response I get for the next three min:

```
2014-03-25 20:16:19,822 INFO    : logging to file: /tmp/tmpsLRy82
2014-03-25 20:16:19,834 INFO    : Calling hook: preflight_check
2014-03-25 20:16:19,835 INFO    : Calling hook: set_defaults
2014-03-25 20:16:19,836 INFO    : Calling hook: bootstrap
```

Eventually it gives an error code:

```
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-18-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-18-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-18-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic_3.11.0-18.32_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is my first time setting up KVMs.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, Ubuntu has deprecated vmbuilder.  Long-time vmbuilder users, like myself, are now forced to find other, supported methods for creating virtual machines - like [virt-builder](http://libguestfs.org/virt-builder.1.html) and virt-install from the [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/) project.  Canonical has abandoned both JeOS and vmbuilder as they move their focus onto non-server deployments (e.g. mobile).  As much as it pains me to say it, this may be part of larger Canonical shifts away from server/cloud support (in perennial pursuit of a profitable business model).

Comment: Can anybody supply a more current view on that?